# Removing words with CAPITAL letters in between

Tags: python, regex

I have words like : 'objQuery', 'Barack Obama', 'expandableMap', 'mh17', 'MH17'. I am cleaning up text which is lightly peppered with coding languages

I want to detect words like 'objQuery' which are continuous i.e. without any whitespace and Capital Letters in between ( more like some coding language tokens) with the help of regexps.

What can be the regular expression to do so?

I tried:

```
re.search(r'\w+[A-Z]+', term)
```

which is taking away proper names too.

I want result too be :

True : 'objQuery', 'expandableMap'

> > Any word that contains Capital Letters in between. Word can start with alphanumeric characters. I can loop through characters and form a boolean function to do so but I am looking for something short.

False: 'Barack Obama', 'mh17', 'MH17'

Comment: Does it have to be a regex?

Comment: No can be something else too given it solves the purpose

Comment: What would be the expected output for the above example?

Comment: Does is have to be `a-z` only? Could it also be `objQuery_23`?

Comment: True for 'objQuery' and 'expandableMap'. False for 'Barack Obama'.

Comment: What about `objM`, or `ExpandableMap`?

Comment: Yeah, any word that contains Capital Letter in between. Word can start with alphanumeric characters. I can loop through characters and form a boolean function to do so but I am looking for something short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this.

```
\b[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)+\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bL1cV0/9)

```
>>> s = "objQuery Barack Obama expandableMapFoo"
>>> m = re.findall(r'\b[a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)+\b', s)
>>> m
['objQuery', 'expandableMapFoo']
```

OR

```
\b[a-z0-9A-Z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)+\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bL1cV0/11)

Comment: but it will not detect ExpandableMap. btw what does (?:) stand for?

Comment: @mousecoder see http://regex101.com/r/bL1cV0/11 . `(?:)` means non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it just something like: `[a-z]+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+`, with whatever word separators are necessary?

Or as, Juan Lopes suggests in a comment, `[a-z]+[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*` if you also want to match strings like `objM`.

Comment: The last + isn't really needed, is it?

Comment: @JuanLopes: Given the string `objMapping`, do you want to match `objMa` or `objMapping`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant it could be a *. Because you want to match objM also.

Comment: @JuanLopes: That could certainly be more valid, but with the current examples it's not clear if that should match or not.

Comment: Sure, just a suggestion :)

Comment: @JuanLopes: Actually, I'm going to throw that in there. The more I look at your suggestion, the more I like it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(word):
    cap = word[0].isupper()
    for i,char in enumerate(word):
        if char == ' ':
            print('whitespace detected. Quitting')
            return False
        if char.isupper() and not cap:
            print('detected upper case in the middle of the word at position', i)
```

Output:

```
In [43]: check('objQuery')
detected upper case in the middle of the word at position 3

In [44]: check('Barack Obama')
whitespace detected. Quitting
Out[44]: False

In [45]: check('expandableMap')
detected upper case in the middle of the word at position 10
```